# Is it possible to "pipe" output from one view engine into another?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was wondering if it is possible (even if it is a *long shot*) to pipe generated markup from one view engine into another with ASP.NET?

Could a view engine be built to explicitly to support such a thing (given the constraint of the ASP.NET Framework)?

What about Web Forms and Razor?

Comment: Here's the age-old question: *Why*? It may help us give you other answers than the one you're explicitly looking for.

Comment: Could you please post complete scenario to understand your exact requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include output from one view (Razor) into the another could you create it as a partial view and call render partial in the other.
Even it your other view is not partial you can create some kind of "adapter partial view" that will call @Html.RenderAction() or @Html.RenderPartial() in order to include the first view.